# How to use excel lambdas and/or array formulas to generate the cross-product of two arrays?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

As a late entrant to using `lambda`s with excel, I"m extremely excited to see how they can simplify my company's sheets.

One area we would love to see simplified: we have a list of values that look like:

| Sites | Values |
| --- | --- |
| Site1 | Value1 |
| Site2 | Value2 |
| Site3 | Value3 |
| Site4 |  |
| Site5 |  |

I would love to have some excel code that, regardless of how many sites and values there are, would be able to generate a cross-product table, eg.

| Site | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Site 1 | Value 1 |
| Site 1 | Value 2 |
| Site 1 | Value 3 |
| Site 1 | Value 4 |
| ... | .. |
| Site 2 | Value 1 |
| Site 2 | Value 2 |
| Site 2 | Value 3 |
| Site 2 | Value 4 |

Is there a way to do this in direct excel formulas, i.e. (a) no macros, and (b) nothing that maintainers will have to click on/manually do every time we add a new site?

Thanks!
/YGA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following formula, `LAMBDA()` helper function or any recursive `LAMBDA()` is not needed:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, TOCOL(A2:A6&" "&TOROW(B2:B4)),
     HSTACK(TEXTBEFORE(α," "),TEXTAFTER(α," ")))
```

---

**Notes:** Just convert the `Sites` and `Values` ranges into `Structured References` aka `Tables` and use the above formula, this is because when structured references are used within a formula it can resize automatically whenever there is a change in the original source.

---

[image]

---

And if both are within one table then:

```
=LET(
     α, TOCOL(Sites[Sites]&" "&TOROW(Sites[Values],1)),
     HSTACK(TEXTBEFORE(α," "),TEXTAFTER(α," ")))
```

---

Comment: Lovely, thank you!

What is the alpha doing in the formula?

Comment: `α` is nothing but a variable which defines the part used within `HSTACK()` with `TEXTBEFORE()` & `TEXTAFTER()`